# Rmarkdown footnote not rendering properly when using sendmailR and viewed in Office365

Tags: r, r-markdown, office365, sendmailr

I've built a HTML document in Rmarkdown and used some footnotes.
In R the rendering occurs correctly and I get nice tasty foonotes.
However when i send using sendmailR...the footnote return symbol is garbled...

[image]

Is this fixable? Any ideas why it's happening?

Comment: Not a solution per se, but I would look into using the blastula package instead. https://github.com/rstudio/blastula

Comment: Thanks Phil. I've also found that Microsoft Office is disabling the embedded links etc... so I have more problems than just this one. I wonder if Blastula would fix that also?

Comment: Yes, it works with that package. You build your emails in an r-markdown document.

Comment: Are you Clancy of the Overflow?

Comment: And an answer came directed in a writing unexpected, I think the same was written by a thumbnail dipped in .tar